# Laravel Eloquent -> get only events where city is

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships, laravel-5

I have a table with:

```
Events
Cities
Clubs
```

The relations are as following:

- An `Event` 'hasOne' `Club`, and a `Club` 'hasMany' `Event`s.
- A `Club` 'hasOne' `City` and a `City` 'hasMany' `Club`s.

I want to add a filter to my query to get all events where the `club.city == 'Oklahoma'`. This is what I tried:

```
$events = Event::where( 'accepted', 1 )
                ->with( [ 'club.city', 'organisation' ] )
                ->where( 'club.city.name', 'Rotterdam' )
                ->orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )
                ->paginate( 6 );
```

Comment: What result did what you try yield? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I  only want to get all the events that are held in Oklahoma. I tryed closure on the with() function but that didnt resulted in what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **whereHas** to filter based on existance of a condition on a relationship.

```
$events = Event::where( 'accepted', 1 )
    ->with( [ 'club.city', 'organisation' ] )
    ->whereHas('club.city', function ($q) use ($cityname) {
        $query->where('name', $cityname);
    })->orderBy( 'created_at', 'asc' )
    ->paginate( 6 );
```